# how to add speech_to_text flutter plugin in project app properly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, speech-to-text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gICC1.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdviD.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWfZT.jpg)

Speech_to_text- 2.7.0
Flutter version- 3.3.10
Dart version- 2.18.6
DevTools version- 2.15.0
minSdkVersion 31
targetSdkVersion 32

build apk for my flutter and dart language app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are using old version of `Speech_to_text` and this version not `null-safty` .

[image]

you can use update from [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text/install) and install version `6.1.1` for Dec-2022 .